# Name of Math Symbol $"\mapsto"$ in the expression $\mathbf{x} \mapsto A \mathbf{x}$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

[image]

I do not know the name of the math symbol with the arrow bracket pointing to the right. Any help identifying it or resource to find it would be helpful. I already checked the LA symbols on Wikipedia and no look. Thanks!

Comment: It's "\mapsto": $x \mapsto Ax$

Comment: In general, use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Wow, that was fast and well said. Thank you, kind sir!

Comment: Thanks Ben! REALLY USEFUL SITE ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol is essentially "maps to", as pointed out in the comments.

As, for its purpose, the maps to symbol describes the input and output of a function, as its name suggests (a input maps to this point)...

See https://wumbo.net/symbol/maps-to/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Gill's answer is a wonderful explanation. Here is what I wish someone told me when I was a linear algebra student as an undergraduate:

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Now, let $f$ $ \subseteq A \times B$ be a map from $A$ to $B$. When we write down a map we state the name of the map followed by the traditional arrow notation from the domain ($A$) to the codomain ($B$). Stacked directly below is the defintion of the map: a description of how every $a \in$ $A$ is assigned exactly one $b \in$ $B$ such as
$$\color{blue} {f : A \to B}$$ $$\color{red}{a \mapsto f(a) = a^2}.$$
Where the line in $\color{blue}{blue}$ reads "$f$ is a map from $A$ to $B$" and the line in $\color{red}{red}$ (to answer your question about $\mapsto$) reads "$f$ maps $a$ to $f(a)$" (where $f(a)$ is precisely $a^2$ in this example).